# Chrome extension placeholder value for manifest field

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest, placeholder

I was wondering if it was possible to set a 'placeholder' value for a field in the `manifest.json` file of a Chrome extension. For example, I just started a new extension and my manifest looks like this :

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "author" : "My Name",
  "name": "Extension Name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Desc",
  "icons": { "16": "icon16.png",
            "48": "icon48.png",
            "128": "icon128.png" },
  "browser_action" : {
      "default_title" : "Extension",
      "default_icon" : {
        "16": "icon32.png",
        "48": "icon48.png",
        "128": "icon128.png" 
        },
      "default_popup" : "dropdown.html",
      "js" : ["dropdown.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts" : [ {
        "matches" : ["http://*/*, https://*/*"],
        "js" : ["some_script.js"]
    } ]
}
```

However, I have not yet made the `icno*.png` files so, obviously, whenever trying to load the extension, chrome says that it can't find the icon files.
Can I do something like :

```
 //[...]
 "default_icon" : {
    //Will be added later
        },
  //[...]
```

or do I have to just delete the `"browser_icon"` and `"icons"` fields and add them later?

I found nothing in the Official Google Documentation.

Comment: The icon files referenced in manifest.json must exist. There's no way around this.

Comment: I guess for now I can just comment out the necessary blocks...

Comment: Or you can copy the same icon file (any random png image) using the specified names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, placeholder values are not permitted in the *manifest.json*.  Many of the fields are checked for validity and/or that the resource is available when the *manifest.json* is loaded.  This is necessary because these values are immediately used. Thus, they *must* be valid. The checking includes verifying the icon files for the `browser_action` and `page_action` keys. These files *must* exist for the extension to be loaded. Overall, what is required to be resolved, in order for the *manifest.json* to load, is explicitly stated in the error displayed when you attempt to load the unpacked extension from `chrome://extensions/`. You will need to resolve all errors in order for the extension to be loaded.

For icon files, you can usually delete the reference, or provide a placeholder icon file that contains an actual graphic. Personally, I just copy one of an assortment of icons I generally use, which are in the public domain, into a generically named icon file (e.g. *icon.png*, or *myIcon.png*, etc.). If you want, you could do a [search for public domain icons](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=public%20domain%20icon) which you could use for this purpose. There are a lot of choices.